# weird and unwanted thick vertical line in Chrome, untraceable in inspector

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

This [site](http://howmuch.dealtas.com) looks usual in Firefox but when I view in chrome (version 31.0.1650.63 m) two weird vertical lines appear which I cannot even trace out in the chrome inspector.

Why does that happen and how to remove that.

[image]

Comment: Seems like an issue with `rtl` class. Remove that and works fine.

Comment: @Danko, renamed the `rtl` class of `body`. Nothing happened

Comment: At my end, it looks just fine in: `IE9`, `Chrome 31.0.1650.57`, `Opera 12.16.1860`, `Firefox 10.0`, and `Safari 5.1.7`.

Comment: @danko, yes  went away by removing the `rtl` class. but what was the reason behind ?

Comment: I think the issue is a combination of rtl and overflow of the left property from ui-helper-hidden-accessible. My answer should allow you to preserve the rtl since it's not really the source of the problem

Answer (score 1):

When I delete this node:

```
<div id="ui-datepicker-div" class="ui-datepicker ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all ui-helper-hidden-accessible"></div>
```

the problem disappears. Testing further, I think the issue is with 
ui-helper-hidden-accessible, specifically the line:

```
left:-99999999px;
```

Firefox drops it entirely as out of range. Chrome probably is having some form of overflow. I suggest using left:-100%; instead.

Comment: I have recreated the same thing. The `direction:rtl` is causing issues with the negative left placement. Tweak `ui-datepicker-div` to fix

Comment: any more explanation about the `some form of overflow` stuff ?

Comment: How was it found that the `ui-datepicker-div`, `left` and `rtl` would cause the problem ? Which rule ?

Comment: I just used the console on firefox (right click, inspect element)
 and poked around. chrome also has an inspector. By some form of overflow what i mean is: it's possible that the way that left: in px is implemented in chrome is as a signed integer value less than 99999999, which would cause overflow of the value, leading to the error you see. in any case using left:-100% is more clear to both the computer and other coders.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the `direction: rtl;` in class `.rtl` on your `body`. Remove this and the strange effect will be gone.

Comment: why the `direction:rtl` should make any problem ?